# Re-register broadcast reciever after destroy android application from tray

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a broadcast that starts a service.
Inside the service, the service creates/update a notification with some parameters (as date, time...).

There are some triggers that call the reciever - as `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `TIME_SET` which I register on the AndroidManifest. But I have also an `ACTION_TIME_TICK` trigger, which I register in `MainActivity` to get it work:

```
        if (ShowNotification()) {
            registerReceiver(myReciever ,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)); 
            GeneralHelper.StartMyService(this, "Main_Activity");
        }
```

**The Problem:** If the user dismiss the application from the application tray, the notification stays (I can see the icon in status bar) but the ACTION_TIME_TICK doesn't work anymore unless I re-open the application manually. I need this broadcast to run in the background also when the application isn't open.